# How do you use JSON_QUERY with null json array inside of json object?

Tags: json, sql-server, json-query

```
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$') from mytable
```

Returns fine the contents of [json] field

```
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$.Guid') from mytable
```

Returns `null`

```
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$.Guid[1]') from mytable
```

Returns `null`

I've also now tried:

```
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$[1].Guid') 
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$[2].Guid') 
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$[3].Guid') 
SELECT JSON_query([json], '$[4].Guid')
```

and they all return `null`

So I'm stuck as to figuring out how create the path to get to the info. Maybe SQL Server `json_query` can't handle the null as the first array?

Below is the string that is stored inside of the `[json]` field in the database.

```
[
  null,
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "15f4fe9d-403c-4820-8e35-8a8c8d78c33b",
    "Team": "2",
    "PlayerNumber": "78"
  },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "8e91596b-cc33-4ce7-bfc0-ac3d1dc5eb67",
    "Team": "2",
    "PlayerNumber": "54"
      },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "f53cd74b-ed5f-47b3-aab5-2f3790f3cd34",
    "Team": "1",
    "PlayerNumber": "23"
    
  },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "30297678-f2cf-4b95-a789-a25947a4d4e6",
    "Team": "1",
    "PlayerNumber": "11"
     }
]
```

Comment: You forgot to tells us what result you actually want...

Comment: `JSON_query([json], '$[1].Guid')` replace 1 with whichever array index you want (zero-based). I suspect you want `JSON_VALUE` not `JSON_QUERY` though

Comment: @Charlieface I just tried that and still got NULL for the Guid.

Comment: @sticky-bit I'm trying to get the Guid values.

Comment: @Charlieface is it possible that the first array being null is causing the problem? I seem to remember trying to concatenate strings in sql and if one of those strings contained a null then the whole string would be null. maybe something similar?

Comment: @user713813: All of them? As JSON array? Or in rows? Or just the one from the second element? Or the first? Be precise, best thing would be a table that looks like the table you expect the query to output. And [edit] the question to add such crucial additional info. Don't hide it in comments.

Comment: And as a side note: Your JSON schema seems fixed. If that assumption is true, you should consider redesigning your database schema get rid of the JSON and store the information the relational way.

Comment: 1. There is only one array here, with a bunch of items in it 2. Concatenation with null irrelevant 3. You *still* haven't told us exactly what you are trying to get. Is it one `Guid` key or all of them?

Comment: @charlieface I'd like to get to all of the Guid's. But I'll take getting to just one to see it work ;)

Comment: You need `JSON_VALUE` for one value, for multiple in rows you will need `OPENJSON`

Comment: @stick-bit it seems fixed but it's not. There are hundreds of pieces of different data. I just simplified it here for the example.

Comment: @charlieface okay, but JSON_value([json], '$[1].Guid') or JSON_value([json], '$.Guid') returns null

Comment: "JSON_value([json], '$[1].Guid') ... returns null" -- No it [does not](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b3372920a24cceddd961043901fb15a).

Comment: @sticky-bit I tried your exact example on my box and it worked. but when the [json] variable comes directly from the table it returns NULL. very strange.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] and post some real sample data for us to work with (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s preferably), as well as expected output

Comment: @stick-bit thanks for your help. when I pasted my full json into your example sql threw the error "incorrect syntax near t" and it turned out there is an apostrophe (the word doesn't) for some of the data. example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b3b9bfbbb4cc606cd7e92fe037aeb0e  to see the error. but apostrophe's have been around a long time inside of json's. why can't it handle it?

Comment: @user713813: Nothing strange about that. In string literals single quotes need to be escaped by doubling them. That's got nothing to do with JSON, all string literals need to follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the comments below your question. I'll just summarize them:

- Probably the most appropriate approach in your case is to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause).
- `JSON_QUERY()` extracts a JSON object or a JSON array from a JSON string and returns `NULL`. If the `path` points to a scalar JSON value, the function returns `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict`mode. The stored JSON doesn't have a `$.Guid` key, so `NULL` is the actual result from the `SELECT JSON_query([json], '$.Guid') FROM mytable` statement.

The following statements provide a working solution to your problem:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (N'[
  null,
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "15f4fe9d-403c-4820-8e35-8a8c8d78c33b",
    "Team": "2",
    "PlayerNumber": "78",
    "TheProblem": "doesn''t"
  },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "8e91596b-cc33-4ce7-bfc0-ac3d1dc5eb67",
    "Team": "2",
    "PlayerNumber": "54"
      },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "f53cd74b-ed5f-47b3-aab5-2f3790f3cd34",
    "Team": "1",
    "PlayerNumber": "23"
    
  },
  {
    "Round": 1,
    "Guid": "30297678-f2cf-4b95-a789-a25947a4d4e6",
    "Team": "1",
    "PlayerNumber": "11"
     }
]')
) v (Json)
```

Statements:

```
SELECT j.Guid
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.Json) WITH (
   Guid uniqueidentifier '$.Guid',
   Round int '$.Round',
   Team nvarchar(1) '$.Team',
   PlayerNumber nvarchar(2) '$.PlayerNumber'
) j

SELECT JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Guid')
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.Json) j
```

Result:

```
Guid
------------------------------------

15f4fe9d-403c-4820-8e35-8a8c8d78c33b
8e91596b-cc33-4ce7-bfc0-ac3d1dc5eb67
f53cd74b-ed5f-47b3-aab5-2f3790f3cd34
30297678-f2cf-4b95-a789-a25947a4d4e6
```